# Moving files on linux, appending existing directories in destination

Tags: linux, file-management

So let's assume I have:

```
dest/dir/file1
dest/dir/file2
dest/dir/subdir/subfile1
dest/dir/subdir/subfile2
```

and

```
src/dir/file3
src/dir/subdir/subfile3
src/dir/newdir/anotherfile
```

... and let's assume there are thousands of files and subdirectories.

Now I want to move all the new files from src to dest, to their respective directories, creating new subdirectories when needed. This would be the equivalent of "**cp -a src/dir dest/**", but as a move operation. The obvious command "**mv src/dir dest/**" fails as the directory already exists in the destination.

How can I do this with one command?

Comment: If there is a `src/dir/file1`, do you want to overwrite it on the `dest` copy? or preserve the older copy there?

Comment: @nik: In this scenario, there shoudn't be, so it doesn't matter. Preserving both dest/dir/file1 and src/dir/file1 would probably be the best option, since it mimics what mv would do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use rsync.

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files src/ dest/
```

Unfortunately that won't remove the directories though. You could just add a further command to remove them.

Comment: Weird that there's no option to remove the directories. This is very close to the intent, anyway, so accepted. Is there a command to every *empty* directory in a directory tree (effectively removing the complete tree, if it is empty)?

Comment: I guess you could do find . -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;

Comment: While this works, I believe it does a copy/delete rather than a more efficient mv operation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not cp -a, the -a switch is the archive switch.

It should be cp -R, the recursive switch.

You can also add the -f switch to force overwrite.

Comment: Yes, but moving does preserve the file ownerships and timestamps, as -a does while -R doesn't. So -a is a better analogy for moving.

Answer (score 2):

While the **rsync** option is better for simply moving files, here is another approach; using **find** to repeatedly invoke **mv**:

```
# First, move directories that don't exist on the destination:
(cd src/dir ; find * -type d -print) | while read f; do
   [ ! -d "src/dir/$f" ] || [ -d "dest/dir/$f" ] || mv "src/dir/$f" "dest/dir/$f"
done
# Then move individual files:
(cd src/dir ; find * -type f -print0) | xargs -0 -n1 -i@ /bin/mv src/dir/@ dest/dir/@

# Alternate to the xargs usage, to allow prompting before overwriting files:
(cd src/dir ; find * -type f) | while read f; do
    /bin/mv -i "src/dir/$f" "dest/dir/$f" </dev/tty
done
```

Note that:

- **_find *** will skip any files/directories that start with a dot (".").
- this will not remove the directories, either.

I use something along these lines, by nightly *cron*, to create any thumbnails of new images in my personal pictures archive, *then* use **rsync** to make a backup of all images on a 2nd machine.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a recursive `mv` is not possible. I would suggest to perform a `cp -R` followed by a `rm -r`.

Comment: However when moving a directory tree from one volume to another, doesn't mv in fact perform a recursive move?

Comment: Unfortunately not. When mv operates on different volumes, it actually perform a cp followed by a rm.